Is there a way to set mempolicy by pid on running precess?
I know that there aren't parameter 'pid' at set_mempolicy() so, I couldn't set mempolicy by pid on running process. (like numactl interleave, membind, etc)
Is there any way to set mempolicy by pid on running process?
I tried to confirm numactl mempolicy code and setting conditions but I couldn' get answer.

I am not sure if it works, but you could try to attach the external process to yours using ptrace() and then use set_mempolicy.
Something like this:

Attach to the target process using ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, 0, 0).
Wait for the target process to stop.
Get the current memory policy of the target process using get_mempolicy() or similar methods.
Modify the memory policy as needed.
Set the new memory policy using set_mempolicy() or similar methods.
Detach from the target process using ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, 0, 0).


What you are describing implies injecting code in the ptraced process, safely making the process execute that code and then removing it and resuming normal execution. This is not a trivial task at all. Using GDB to attach to the process and issue a call set_mempolicy(...) (that does exactly what you describe under the hood) would be an order of magnitude easier!
